# How can I resolve critical error on this website. after migrating a WordPress website from one hosting plan to another within GoDaddy?

Tags: wordpress, migration

[Working website in old Hosting (image from old hosting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE8wf.jpg)
[after migrating to new hosting in godaddy itself (image from new hosting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZX1j.png)

tried to Switch to Default Theme and back to original theme, but it doesn't work
and i'm new to godaddy and backend issues

Comment: Provide what errors you get / what is in the logs. Disable all plugins and see if this helps. Maybe you didnt migrate it properly ? We can only guess. Contact the hosting for support ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering might stem from a conflict with a plugin or theme. Since you've attempted to switch themes already without success, the next step is to enable debugging using "WP_DEBUG" to pinpoint the error. WordPress documentation offers comprehensive guidance on debugging, which you can access here: [WordPress Debugging Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/debug/debug-wordpress/).

To enable debugging, you'll need to access the wp-config.php file in the Godaddy file manager:

1. Navigate to My Products.
2. Choose Hosting/WordPress Managed Hosting.
3. Select the domain of the website in question.
4. Click on Manage.
5. At the bottom right of the settings page, you'll find the option for the file manager.

From there, you can access the wp-config.php file and make the necessary changes to enable debugging. This should provide more detailed information about the issue, helping you troubleshoot it effectively.